# incompatible character encodings utf-8 and windows-1251, installing ruby, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, utf-8, windows-1251

I don't know much about this stuff, help me, please. I was installing ruby  [railsinstaller-windows](https://github.com/PaulineNemchak/railsinstaller-windows) 
on step 9 there was a problem

[image]

What should I do? I need a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that happens because the path where you are installing Ruby, contains non-ASCII characters (i.e. your username, try to rename it).

Comment: yes, i guess too, but is there another way to solve the problem?

Comment: @ПолинаНемчак try to clone repo into different folder and install from there.